# Flink DataSource Iterate

Tags: hadoop, datasource, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to iterate the data source:

```
     val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
      env.setParallelism(1)

      val job = Job.getInstance
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(
        job,
        new Path("file.parquet.gz")
      )

      val hadoopInputFormat: HadoopInputFormat[Void, GenericRecord] =
        new HadoopInputFormat(
          new AvroParquetInputFormat[GenericRecord],
          classOf[Void],
          classOf[GenericRecord],
          job
        )
       val data: DataSource[tuple.Tuple2[Void, GenericRecord]] = env.createInput(hadoopInputFormat)
```

When i do data.print i can see the data in tuple.

But when i do :

```
    data.map
     {
       res =>
         println("!!!!!!!!!!!111")
         println( res.f1)
     }
```

Nothing gets printed.

I want to iterate the data source and fetch the GenericRecord. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute a Flink batch program without calling `print` or `collect`, you need to call `env.execute()`. Only this call will trigger the execution of the program in the absence of the above-mentioned API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data.collect then afterwards use:
data.iterator().next() to iterate